# How to prove $x^2+y^2\geq y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

Intuitive it's easy to see that $x^2+y^2\geq y^2$ is true, but I want to prove this.

**My attempt:**

> I know $a^2\geq 0$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$.
>
> I let $a=x-y$ so
>
> \begin{align}
> &(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2\geq 0 \\ 
> &\iff x^2+y^2\geq 2xy
> \end{align}
>   But I'm stuck here, what is the next step?

*A second question*. If I instead have a strict inequality $x^2+y^2> y^2$, this is only valid if $x\neq 0$, right?

Comment: The latest edit suggests you're looking for a proof that starts by deducing $x^{2} + y^{2} \geq 2xy$ for all real $x$, $y$. Unfortunately, there's no obvious way to get from this inequality to the desired inequality: The natural next step is "erase what you have so far, and proceed as in the existing answers".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $x^2\geq 0$, where equality holds if and only if $x=0$. Therefore
$$ x^2+y^2 \geq 0 + y^2 = y^2 $$
and equality holds if and only if $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$x^2 \geqslant 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, with equality for $x=0$.